# Kivy-how can i make my canvas height smaller than the parent height

Tags: canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I have a stacklayout with a canvas and an image. my image has a size_hint of .1 and I want my canvas to have the same height as my image.

.kv file:

```
StackLayout:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Image:              
        size_hint_y: .1
        source: 'Images\login\cptbanner.jpg'
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True
```

what can I do to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Kivy canvas is not a widget or the space in which you paint. It is only a set of instructions. You can´t resize it. I guess you want to resize the drawn rectangle. I'm not sure what the outcome is you expect, but you can resize the rectangle using the `width` and `height` attributes of the parent widget:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


Builder.load_string("""
<MainWindow>:
    StackLayout:
        id : aa
        orientation: 'lr-tb'

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, self.height*0.9
                size: self.width, self.height*0.1

        Image:
            id: im
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            source: 'Images\login\cptbanner.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
""")

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. can you please explain why your multiplying self.height*0.9 and self.height*0.1? thanks!

Comment: `size: self.width, self.height*0.1` is equivalent to `size_hint: 1, 0.1` (we can´t use `size_hint` with Rectangle). `Pos: 0, self.height * 0.9` allows us to position the rectangle in the correct way --> x = 0,  y = (height of the father - height of the rectangle). (height of the father - height of the rectangle) is the same as (height of the father * 0.9).  I hope you get something out of this,  my English is not very good ... :(

Comment: your English is good enough brother, I understood everything perfectly, thank you for all the help.